# Castalia 3.2 energy consumption

Tags: omnet++, energy, consumption

I’m developing several application protocols in Castalia 3.2. Compilation succeeds and timing results are right but when I try to obtain energy consumption the result is 612000 for every node and for every protocol. I’ve tried CastaliaResults -i 100812-102156.txt -s energy But results are always 612000 I also set initialenergy to 1000 in omnetpp.ini and the results are always 1000. The resulting time is right and the radio parameters are the default. Can anyone tell me why the results are not the expected and the steps to obtain the energy consumption?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in using `CastaliaResults -i yourfile.txt -s energy` to see the energy results, it's just that the results are not what you expect.

We cannot know the details of your protocols since you did not share, but what seems to be happening is that your protocols keep the radio on **all of the time**.
If you are also transmitting packets in your simulations I would expect to see some very minor variation (Tx power is a little less than Rx/listening power). Are there any transmissions and do you see any minor difference?

Where does the number 612000 come from? Is this the total energy of your nodes? If so then obviously there is another problem: nodes do not have enough energy for the task you want them to complete.

Finally, I would encourage you to use the latest version of Castalia from the Github repository. There are several improvements compared to 3.2 and many bug fixes.

Comment: The task is completed but for every number of nodes the energy result is the same 612000.

Comment: How can I tune the radio so that it is not always on?

Comment: You say that you are developing protocols in Castalia but it seems you are not sure about the basics. Study the manual and if you have specific questions, ask a new question in Stackoverflow. Here's a guide to help you ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you found this answer useful you can upvote and accept it. If you have follow on questions, you should ask them in seperate questions.